# API JWT guard and web session guard in Laravel

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-jwt

I am trying to make Laravel using multiple guards - depending on the authentication type.

When I am authenticating via API, I would like to use `jwt` guard. When I am authenticating through web, I want to use `session` guard.

My `config\auth.php` looks like this:

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
```

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
            //'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
]
```

My `routes/web.php` looks like this:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

My `routes/api.php` looks like this:

```
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
Route::get('me', 'AuthController@me');
```

What I am getting is that API authentication works fine, while the web doesn't. I have debugged and it seems like it is always checking the `jwt` guard.

Can someone help me, how can I set the guard on a route if that is possible or on `Auth::routes()` call?

Comment: you would have to specify the guard to use when dealing with any actions from the 'web' routes ... or you would have to apply the `auth` middleware with the `web` param, `auth:web` so that it will set the default to `web` for the routes protected by that middleware ... most of those controllers for auth have defined middleware in their constructors

Comment: @lagbox can you help me out how would you do it? Do you think that I wrap up `routes/web.php` code in `Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:web']], function () {`?

Comment: no because everything does not require authentication to be reach and those controllers define their middleware in their constructor ... it would probably be easier for you to leave the default guard as `web` and modify what you need for the "api" side

Comment: @lagbox That was my first idea and I tried it like that, but then I was struggling to authenticate using API, since it was always requiring token (even on login urls)

Comment: because the `auth` middleware is only applied to routes that require an authenticated user; a login route must allow unauthenticated users to reach it otherwise they could not authenticate

Comment: @lagbox I have switched now to `web` as default guard. I can login, but I can't authenticate using the API, since I am getting this error: `Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::factory does not exist.`. It seems like it is using the wrong guard again (trying to use session guard for API authentication)

Comment: i dont know what you are doing in your routes so i have no idea how you are attempting to authenticate, but any time you are dealing with the `Auth` facade (auth manager) and you want to use the guard that isn't the default you have to tell it which guard to use `Auth::guard(...)->...`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by switching default to `web` routes.

Then I updated the code for `app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php` to use the specific `api` auth wherever I was using the `auth` method:

`auth('api')->attempt($validator->validated())` and `'expires_in' => auth('api')->factory()->getTTL() * 60`